# Order of attributes on the product page

Tags: product, php, product-attribute, magento2.1.6

I found how add my custom attribute "dispname" on the product page but I would like to put it above the attribute "name". Can you help me?

catalog_product_view.xml :

[image]

Product page :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code in your xml file

```
<move element="product.info.dispname" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
```